# Selecting specific values from a table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have searched similar questions and given it some thought but I am new to python and can't seem to figure this out. I am trying to scrape data from the player table on this page:

http://www.rotoworld.com/teams/depth-charts/mlb.aspx

The HTML for each entry (player) is for example:

```
<td><b>3B</b></td><td>1. <a href='/player/mlb/6242/manny-machado'>Manny Machado</a></td>
```

So I can run

```
players=soup.select('td > a')
```

to get a list of all players. However I would like to select only players of a specific position, i.e. all the 3B, SS etc. The position is just another text string, and I can't seem to differentiate by it. Does anybody have any idea where I might be able to start with this?

**Edit:** of course this would be simple if the same positions were always in the same rows, e.g. 1B always rows 2-3 but as can be seen from the table this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the rows of data and check siblings:

```
for row in soup.findAll('tr'):
    cell = row.findNext('td')
    if cell.text == '3B':
        print(cell.next_sibling.find('a'))
```

Which will output:

```
<a href="/player/mlb/6242/manny-machado">Manny Machado</a>
```

Comment: Ah ok, that's great! Thanks very much.